# Accesing the data from an input button for Vue

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I installed the Vuetify upload button with npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuetify-upload-button).
However there is little documentation on it and I am not sure how to read the data that is selected when the input button is used.

**HTML(part)**:

```
<upload-btn title="select" name="pinimage">test</upload-btn>

<v-btn
  :disabled="!valid"
  @click="submit"
>
  submit
</v-btn>
```

**JS:**
(See the submit function where I try to log the selected data)

```
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
import UploadButton from 'vuetify-upload-button';

export default {
    name: "addinspiration",

    components: {
        'upload-btn': UploadButton
    },

    computed: {
        ...mapState([
            'backenderror'
        ])
    },

    data: () => ({
        backenderror: '',
        valid: true,
        email: '',
        pinimage: '',
    }),

    methods: {
        submit () {
            console.log(this.pinimage.files);
            this.$store.dispatch('AddInspiration', {
                pinimage: this.pinimage.files,
            });
        },
        clear () {
            this.$refs.form.reset()
        }

    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstood your question then you could also try like this.

According to its [documentation](https://github.com/DoritoBandito/vuetify-upload-button), `fileChangedCallback` is a callback for when a file is selected, returns a `File` object and its default value is `undefined`.
Thus, you could use [FileReader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read the data of the file.

**HTML**

```
<upload-btn :fileChangedCallback="getFile"></upload-btn>
```

**JS**

```
data() {
    return {
        myFile: ''
    }
},

methods:  {
    getFile (file) {
          let vm = this
          let reader = new FileReader()

          reader.onload = e => {
              vm.myFile = e.target.result
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(file)
     }
}
```